# Quickly scrape the content of a page using capybara despite some useless assets on the page taking too long to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, capybara

I am using Capybara to **scrape** websites to check if they use cookies and if they have banners that explain why they use cookies (that may be generated using javascript).

Here is the code to initialize Capybara :

```
def init_capybara
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'

  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, phantomjs: Phantomjs.path, js_errors: false)
  end

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

Here is my code for the scraper :

```
def presence(url)
  init_capybara

  @browser = Capybara.current_session
  @browser.visit(url)

  cookies = @browser.evaluate_script("document.cookie")

  return cookies
end
```

The **scraper** for the banner works the same way.

I expect to get a string of all the cookies used in the website.

But I get a timeout error if I try to **scrape** a webpage that needs content that takes a long time to load (e.g. an analytics tool that takes a minute to load) although I do not need this content to proceed.

I do not want to just put a longer "default_max_wait_time" because the analysis needs to take only a few second and for most of the websites it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy solution, except editing `/etc/hosts` while testing in order to disable the offending domains.

**Edit**: it seems to be a better solution:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
config.before(:each, js: true) do
  page.driver.browser.url_blacklist = ["http://use.typekit.net"]
end
```

Source: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/speed-up-javascript-capybara-specs-by-blacklisting-urls#a-better-way

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @mdesantis is on the right track, however the article linked to is for `capybara-webkit` not `Poltergeist`.  With Poltergeist it should really just be configured in the driver setup (rather than a before block) and you probably also want to tell PhantomJS not to load images - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, 
    phantomjs: Phantomjs.path, 
    js_errors: false,
    phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no'],
    url_blacklist: ['*/analytics_tool.js'] # can use * and ? wildcards in these
  )
end
```